# Warning is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect after Upgrade to 5.1.2

Tags: php-errors, ee5

> Warning  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/home/vg000web02/15/07/7010715/web/themes//ee) is not within the
>   allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/:/tmp/) 
>   ee/legacy/libraries/Core.php, line 196

Tried a number of possible solutions but nothing worked so far.
The error prevents from making any updates to the site.

Please advice.
Thanks,
-Vadim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error looks like it is being caused by a path configuration issue - check that the settings for [URL and Paths](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v5/cp/settings/urls.html) on your site are set correctly.  (go to Control Panel / Settings / General Settings / URL and Paths).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Changing "URL and Paths" combined with changing open_basedir to "none" fixed the problem.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If possible turn off the open basedir restriction.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work after updating the path and you have cache enabled, try to disable and enable the cache.